# How to load data on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have more than one data and I want to load  ajax when scroll reaches 80% or near doesn't matter..I try to use [jscroll](http://jscroll.com/)but I couldn't achieve than I would like to ask how can I do that ?

```js
   $('.lazy_content').each(function() {
            var data_url = $(this).data("url");
            var data_id = $(this).data("target-id");
            var target = $("#" + data_id);

            $.ajax({
                url: data_url,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    target.html("");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(data).each(function(index, el) {
                        target.append(el);
                    });
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        target.html('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    } else {
                        target.html('Unexpected error.');
                    }
                }
            });

        })
```

```css
.lazy_content{
  border-bottom:3px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-1-comments" data-target-id="PostsArea">
  <h4>COMMENTS</h4>
  <div id="PostsArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-2-posts" data-target-id="CommentsArea">
  <h4>POSTS</h4>
  <div id="CommentsArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-3-users" data-target-id="UsersArea">
  <h4>USERS</h4>
  <div id="UsersArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-4-forums" data-target-id="ForumsArea">
  <h4>FORUMS</h4>
  <div id="ForumsArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-5-us" data-target-id="UsArea">
  <h4>FORUMS</h4>
  <div id="UsArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-6-text" data-target-id="textArea">
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <div id="textArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-8-content" data-target-id="contentArea">
  <h4>CONTENT</h4>
  <div id="contentArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="lazy_content" data-url="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-7-last" data-target-id="lastArea">
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <div id="lastArea">
    <div id="loading"><img src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/assets/img/loading.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[please click to see full page](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/JWQaww)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the position of your window's top border (`$(window).scrollTop()`), current window's height (`$(window).height()`) and the absolute height of a document (`$(document).height()`). Position of your bottom border is position of your top border + window's height, right? So, the moment when your bottom border reaches the bottom of a document can be calculated this way:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()
```

and it can be adjusted (as you said about 80%):

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() * 0.8
```

And combine it with a `scroll` handler:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var reachedBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() * 0.8;

   if (reachedBottom) {
       # whatever you want to do
   }
});
```

Comment: I knew this way but I got some bug if I reached bottom than content goes on again

Answer (score 0):

what about using `body.offsetTop` proprtional to body total height?